# Jira Atlassian API Pagination

Tags: powerbi, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I've used the JIRA API a few timees, but only for small extracts so I've never had to use pagniation to return more results than the max result.

Here's the documentation for the API: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#expansion

I have a query to the API:

```
let


Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("*connection URL*,
[Headers=[Accept="application/json"]])),


#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),


>Expand the scheme, and define the field data types etc


in

 
#"Changed Type"
```

I can see form the documentation I need to use something like this:

```
{

    "startAt" : 0,

    "maxResults" : 10,

    "total": 200,

    "isLast": false,

    "values": [

        { /* result 0 */ },

        { /* result 1 */ },

        { /* result 2 */ }

    ]

}
```

**I'm not sure where the pagination would fit into this?** Can anyone help me? I need to return 1500 results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make multiple REST requests that iterate through all of the results [one "page" at a time](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/#pagination):

1. Read the API response from JIRA and capture the values of `maxResults` and `startAt` in the response.
2. Add the value of `maxResults` to `startAt`, update your REST API call `startAt` parameter, and call the same API endpoint again.
3. Repeat until `startAt` is greater than or equal to `total`, or until `isLast` is true.

A `while` loop is a natural fit for an operation like this. To minimize API calls, you should use a larger value for `maxResults` so you receive more data in each loop.

Comment: Thanks so much, will I have to make multiple queries, or can I loop the start at & end at in my code somehow? I'm a complete novice!

Comment: No worries! You will need to make multiple queries (as described in step 2 above) until you've retrieved all results.

Answer (score 0):

below is sample python script to call JQL Filter API and loop through paginated results.

Each list call returns three fields

```
'startAt': 0, 'maxResults': 50, 'total': 141,
```

You have to call API until you reach total.

```
import json
import requests

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization" : "Bearer Personal-access-token"
}

BASE_URL = 'https://my.company.com'
jql_url = f'{BASE_URL}/rest/api/latest/search'

query = {
    'jql'       : 'Your JQL Filter query',
    'startAt'   : 0,
}

def my_operation_function(issue_data):
    issue_key = issue_data['key']
    issue_fields = issue_data['fields']
    print(f'issue_key\t:\t{issue_key}')

response = requests.request("GET", jql_url, headers=headers, params=query)
data=json.loads(response.text)

'''
>>> data
{'expand': 'schema,names', 'startAt': 0, 'maxResults': 50, 'total': 141, 'issues': [{'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '27825703', 'self': 'https://myjira.site.com/rest/api/latest/issue/27825703', 'key': 'ABC-123', 'fields': {'customfield_21400': None, 'customfield_19200': None, 'customfield_18111': None, 'customfield_19201': None, 'customfield_18112': None, 'customfield_18113': None, 'customfield_19202': None, 'customfield_19203': None, 'customfield_18114': None, 'customfield_18110': None,
'''

issues=data['issues']
for issue in issues:
    find_keywords(issue)

while query['startAt'] < data['total']:
    query['startAt'] += 50
    print(f"\nstartAt = {query['startAt']}")
    response = requests.request("GET", jql_url, headers=headers, params=query)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    issues=data['issues']
    for issue in issues:     
        my_operation_function(issue)
```